# Configure DI using Json config

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to set up configurable DI using the new JSON config?

I.e. I have two classes that implement the same interface, can I use the JSON config to specify which class to inject.

For example:
Given two classes

```cs
public class RealService: IService {...}
public class FakeService: IService {...}
```

and `appsettings.json`:

```json
"ServiceImplementation": "FakeService"
```

and in `Startup.cs`

```cs
void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
     var serviceNameToInject = Configuration["ServiceImplementation"];
     IService serviceToInject = Type.GetType(serviceNameToInject )
     service.AddTransient<IService, serviceToInject >
     ....
```

I assume something like this would work but it doesn't feel right, so is there a better way to achieve Json configurable DI using the new ASP.NET Core MVC framework?

Thanks in advance,
Michael McD.

Comment: Yes and no. You can add configuration to json, but you got to process them yourself in code. No out of box way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the out of Service container doesn't support JSON/XML Configuration. ASP.net core allows you to replace the default container with an IOC container of your choice: some of which support JSON and XML configuration such as Autofac.

You can read more about JSON and XML config of Autofac here: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html#configuring-with-microsoft-configuration

And how to configure Autofac in Asp.net Core Over here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html?highlight=addtransient#replacing-the-default-services-container

Comment: Hi Martin - I think this is the approach we'll take if we endup needing more than one configurable dependency.  For now we've "rolled our own" solution as per @Tseng suggestion.  Oh and thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

No out-of-the-box support yet.

You may use reflection to do that work yourself while adding sections in your `appSettings.json`. However, please be aware that your code might not be compilable under [.NET Native](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx).

Another question that you may ask yourself at that moment is... when are you are swapping implementations. Are you doing redeploying your whole application at the same time? If yes, why not have it in code and gain the benefits of static typing?

At that point, it's an architectural consideration and positive and negative must be weighted in.

Comment: Hi Maxime - funnily enough it's our in-house architect that's suggesting we have configurable DI.  But yes we are making use of static typing and the new MVC  6 DI for the most part which we're really happy with.